# "to set a man framing titillating hypotheses". What does it mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, gerunds, gerund-clauses

I am reading a book right now. I saw a phrase and I couldn't understand what it means. What does "to set a man framing titillating hypotheses" mean?

(Emphasis below is mine)

> I can only see her lips – cherry-red lipstick – and her teeth, ideally crafted and cocaine-white. Maybe that’s a promise of a smile. Or maybe she just wants **to set a man framing titillating hypotheses** with that single, slight movement of her lips? Nothing serious… just for practice.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Try: to frame a hypothesis, first. To set here means to get (induce) a man to do something.

Comment: Are you sure about your transcription there? There's a grammatical error I wouldn't expect to see in a published work.

Comment: SamBC, why don't you say what you think the error is?

Comment: You need to make your own attempt. Where is that?

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting one to pull apart, this. Several relatively obscure words.

We can see that ***set*** is a verb, here. One clue is that it has *to* in front of it. So, she "wants to set...", but what? Set has a lot of senses, and some are transitive, some are intransitive, and some are transitive and then require an additional noun, noun phrase, adjective, adjectival phrase, prepositional phrase (etc.) to indicate the precise meaning. We could parse this a number of ways!

However, just two possibilities in terms of the structure of the parse are plausible. Either the whole rest of the phrase up to 'with' is a noun phrase, the object of *to set*, or it is a noun phrase as object *and* there's an additional adjectival or nominal (or whatever) after that. Let's look at the series of words in question:

"to set **a man framing titillating hypotheses**"

Fortunately, we can immediately eliminate the possibility of the bold portion being a single noun phrase. If it were, the main noun would be ***hypotheses***, a plural, but the phrase starts with an indefinite article, indicating that it is singular.

So, it must be an object and a noun phrase, adjective, or similar. That's easy to understand - because "**framing**" is a gerund, so "framing titillating hypotheses" is a gerund phrase (which is a sort of noun phrase) with the object of the verb *to frame* being ***titillating hypotheses***.

So, the author is suggesting the woman might want to:

> set (a man) (framing (titillating hypotheses))

In this sense, *set* means to cause the object to be in a certain state or position. That state is the gerund phrase "framing titillating hypotheses".

*To frame*, as used here, means to construct in one's mind. *Frame* has quite a wide range of meanings, but to frame a hypothesis only really fits a couple of them - to bring into being (which is a fairly obscure meaning), to construct in one's mind, or to set out in words. Taking the whole context, I am confident that this is intended to be a construction in mind. We might say "imagine", but there is a stronger implication of working things out thoroughly, and to some extent logically.

*Titillating hypotheses* is a conventional adjective+noun pair. *Hypotheses* is the plural of *hypothesis*, meaning a possible explanation or prediction - essentially, a very technical term for speculation. *Titillating* means sexually arousing.

Thus, the author is suggesting that the woman may want to cause a man to imagine sexually arousing possibilities with a slight movement of her lips.

Comment: There is not one obscure word in the entire text.